# Rolling Horizon approach for solving a job scheduling problem

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, reference-request, scheduling

I am trying solve a scheduling problem adopting a rolling horizon approach. I have developed an Integer programming model and seek to speed up execution.

I am seeking advice on beginner level literature on the topic - papers/articles/books and any other materials that would help me to learn this approach. I found it difficult to find sufficient information as most of it is mainly from research papers where it is either too complex or too vaguely described with no examples at all.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some papers you could read. [This](https://optimization-online.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/7809.pdf) makes an introduction to the topic, explains why it is useful, what are some drawbacks and proposes an algorithm to deal with them. Also, it provides two different use cases, lot sizing optimization and tail optimization. [This](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2019/4739376/) provides an example of a crane scheduling problem, with very complete explanations.  And also, you could check [this very good answer](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/7738/10165) to a question posted some time ago, in which the logic about rolling periods is explained.

Comment: This answer would benefit from summaries of content at the links. At present, this is a link-only answer.

Comment: You are right, updating.