# Implement a rolling horizon approach into a schedulig problem

Tags: linear-programming, scheduling

I have just come across the topic of 'Rolling Horizon' in my literature research and would now like to apply it myself, but unfortunately I don't know where to start. This is my model, which is supposed to work with a rolling approach.

\begin{align}
&\min \sum_{t,s}^{}slack_{t,s}\\
&\sum_{s}^{}work_{j,t,s}+slack_{t,s}=demand_{t,s}\quad \forall j,t\\
&\sum_{l=t}^{t+5}\sum_{s}^{}work_{j,l,s}\le 5\quad \forall j,t\\
&\sum_{s}^{}work_{j,t,s}\le 1\quad \forall j,t
\end{align}

How exactly do I need to extend/modify the model so that I can implement and run such an approach? Is there any good literature where I can read up further on the subject?

Comment: The first reply on this thread may help: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/7714/is-there-any-recommended-rolling-horizon-in-optimization-literature-for-beginn

Comment: BTW, what is the reason you want to use this approach? Do you have some stochastic parameters? Or solving over a long horizon is required but intractable?

Comment: The reasoning behind the implementation is the unsolvability.